# The normal equation of the plane that contains the line $(1,1,1) + t(-2,0,3)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Determine the equation of the plane that contains the point $(4,2,-1)$
>   and also the line $L: (1,1,1) + t(-2,0,3)$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

The direction vector $(-2,0,3)$ of the line is also a direction vector for the plane.

We can get a vector orthogonal to the plane by solving

$$(x,y,z) \cdot (-2,0,3) = 0$$

$$-2x+3z = 0$$

One valid solution would be $(3,1,2)$.

So we have that $(3,1,2)$ is orthogonal to the plane. And since $(4,2,-1)$ belongs to it, a normal equation for the plane can be calculated this way:

$$(x,y,z)\cdot (3,1,2) = (4,2,-1) \cdot (3,1,2)$$

$$3x+y+2z = 12$$

---

But that's wrong. If the plane contains the line $L$, it should also contain the point

$$(1,1,1)+5\cdot(-2,0,3) = (-9,1,16)$$

But it doesn't:

$$3(-9)+(1)+2(16) = -27 + 1 + 32 = 8 \not = 12$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Pay attention in this part: "We can get a vector orthogonal to the plane by solving". Take care here! The process that you have described don't gives necessarily a vector which is orhogonal to the plane, can lies to the plane and to be orthogonal to the line. A better process is the following: pick up any point of the line, then constuct a vector starting from that point and finishing in the outer line point, now you have the second vector to work.

Comment: Intuitively, the problem should only have one unique solution. it's correct that this vector is orthogonal to the direction vector. The problem is there are infinite vectors that are orthogonal to that vector, so the equation $2x - 3z = 0$ has infinite solutions. You can't just pick one of them and say that's the right one, because there's isn't enough information. Try looking at the things you haven't used (like the 2 points) and find a second condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One valid solution would be $(3,1,2)$.

This is incorrect. Not all vector perpendicular to $(-2,0,3)$ gives you the normal vector of the plane. The correct way is pick a point on the line, for simplicity say $(1,1,1)$ then the normal vector of plane is perpendicular to $(-2,0,3)$ and $(4,2,-1)-(1,1,1)=(3,1,-2)$. Hence you need to calculate $n=(-2,0,3)\times (3,1,-2)$

Then the plane is given by $<(x,y,z)-(1,1,1), n>=0$

Comment: @ZolTunKul Suppose $n$ is the normal of a plane $P$, and $p_0\in P$, then every point $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$ is on the plane if and only if $x-p_0$ is perpendicular to $n$, that is $<x-p_0,n>=0$

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is: 
You already have one vector and one point then:
Let $L : B + t\overrightarrow{w}$ where $\overrightarrow{w} = (-2,0,3) \wedge B = (1,1,1), t \in \mathcal{R}$

Let $ C = (4,2,-1)$ 
You look for a plane that contains this line and $C$, now:
Let $\overrightarrow{z} = \overrightarrow{CB} = \overrightarrow{B-C}$ Let $H$ be the plane defined by the parametric equation:

$H : B \ + \ h \overrightarrow{z} \ + \ t \overrightarrow{w}; t,h \in \mathcal{R}$

This plane portrays these conditions(Portrays? I'm sorry for my English)

Another approach could be:
Let $\overrightarrow{a} = \overrightarrow{w} \times \overrightarrow{z}$ then it's $(x,y,z)$ coordinates represent the coefficients of the Cartesian equation of the desired plane. Let these coordinates be $a_1,a_2 \wedge a_3$ respectively: now the equation of the plane:
$a_1(x-4) + a_2(y-2) + a_3(z+1)= 0$ is the Cartesian equation of the plane.

Answer (score 1):

The plane is passing through two points and one line....

$(x_1,y_1,z_1) = (4,2,−1)$

$(x_2,y_2,z_2) = (1,1,1)$

$(l,m,n) = (−2,0,3)$

`Cartesian equation`
\begin{equation}
\begin{vmatrix}
x-x_1 & y-y_1 & z-z_1\\
x_2-x_1 &y_2-y_1 &z_2-z_1\\
l    & m    & n 
\end{vmatrix} = 0
\end{equation}