# Why isn't the orthogonal vector to a direction vector of a plane not necessarily perpendicular to such plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

I had made [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/988509/5775), and the problem with my exercise was that I was trying to calculate a vector perpendicular to some plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$: given one line $L$ inside the plane, I grabbed the direction vector $(-2,0,3)$ of this line and then solve

$$(x,y,z) \cdot (-2,0,3) = 0$$

To get an orthogonal vector to the plane. But I was told that

> Not all vector perpendicular to $(−2,0,3)$ gives you the normal vector
>   of the plane.

However I don't really see why. If $(-2,0,3)$ is a direction vector of the plane, why wouldn't a vector perpendicular to $(-2,0,3)$ necessarily be also perpendicular to said plane? In $\mathbb{R}^3$, at least, I can't really *visualize* why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector perpendicular to your line will be just that, perpendicular to your line; nothing more is guaranteed. To be perpendicular to the plane, you must be perpendicular to *all* vectors (or lines) in the plane at once; there is only one direction (and its opposite) which does that. The vector you found perpendicular to $(2,0,-3)$ could very well be *inside* the plane; there is certainly a direction *within* the plane that is perpendicular to your line. Or your perpendicular vector could happen to be a normal vector to the plane. Or anything in between.

One really cannot tell more just knowing that the vector is perpendicular to $(2,0,-3)$.

Comment: Would the same apply parallel vectors? I mean, if I find a vector that is parallel to that line's direction vector, would it also be parallel to the plane?

Comment: @ZolTunKul: A line being parallel to a plane has a different definition than being perpendicular: it suffices to be parallel to _some_ line in the plane (being parellel to all lines of the plane at once is clearly impossible)